# How to use READ - FTPs in Mule

Tags: ftp, mule, anypoint-studio, mule4, mule-connector

I am trying to pass a .csv file that came to me via FTPs, it comes in a binary format (I think) and I want to pass it to some format where I can edit the columns and rows.

I use Anypoint Studio version: 7.12.1, FTPS connector 1.7.1, Runtime version 4.4.0 EE

read XML:

```
<ftps:read doc:name="Read" doc:id="34e4139b-606e-4cd0-8650-4e3b2bab01d7" config-ref="FTPS_Config_OneHub" path="test_Dec.csv"/>
```

I'm doing it with a transform message:

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="165835a6-da27-442a-82bd-a3a28552611f" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
read(payload, "application/string")]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
```

But I get the following error:

```
""You called the function 'AnonymousFunction' with these arguments: 
  1: Array ([{"PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\b\b\b\u0000": "q",column_1: "^",column_2: ""}, ...)
  2: String ("application/string")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String | Binary
  2: String
  3: Object


4| read(payload, "application/string")
   ^^^^
Trace:
  at anonymous::main (line: 4, column: 1)" evaluating expression: "%dw 2.0
output application/csv
---
read(payload, "application/string")"."
```

The payload with the file looks like this:

```
PK  (\!T         [Content_Types].xmlµSËnÂ0ü•È×*6ôPUEƒMCÇ©ô\{“Xø%¯¡ð÷]8”R‰
```

ƒM†õ9Ç!PEƒMEƒMõà$òEƒMÁEƒEƒMMÒ†äd¦cêD”j);·£ÑPÁgð¹ÎEƒMEƒM'OÐÊ•ÍÕEƒMãî¾H7LÆh’™R‰µ×G¢EƒMEƒMõ^'EƒMEƒM°

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you download the file with some other client (like filezilla) and verify if the file is valid CSV?

Comment: the `.csv` in the name does not necessarily means that the file is csv. from your comment on aled's answer, it is pretty clear that the file is a comprised archive and not a CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input file is not a CSV. It is zip file. You should first decompress it and then see if it has a CSV file inside. You can use the [Compression Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/compression-module/2.1/) in Mule to decompress it.

Comment: it works thanks you a lot, just that is necessary to use the extract module